# AWS ebs volume snapshots automated vs. Manual

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a daily snapshot and understand that the snapshots are incremental, and would only take a snapshot of the difference from the last backup.

So if I take a manual snapshot, would it know to diff from my last automated snapshot? Or does it only know to diff manual snapshots?

Answer (score 2):

The way snapshot works are:
It won't be differentiating between an automated backup or a Manual backup. It checks the existing backup (either a Manual or Automated one) and adds the delta on top of it. [image] .If you have deleted the First backup, then the Second backup becomes the point of reference and it creates a soft link with reference to it.